# How to show the dimensions of a document as a ratio

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When we are using Image size window, width and height is displayed in percentage, pixel, inches etc. I need to get a pop up window showing the dimension of the document in ratios. Is this possible?

Comment: The math to calculate the ratio is pretty easy and there are tons of online calculators to do it for you.  I Googled "display ratio calculator" and found plenty.

Comment: Doesn't `View > Pixel Aspect Ratio` tell you the ratio of the current active document?

Comment: Or do you mean the sort of thing where instead of 75%, 76%, 77%, 78%... you get 3:4, 19:25, 77:100, 39:50... ? That would make the spinner/slider (click and drag) annoying and hard to read.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. First, where do you want to "show" the dimensions, on the lower left corner of PS screen? Why? The second question is do you want to show the dimensions as ratio or do you want to end up with a given ratio?

Comment: Hi Manu, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick script that will calculate the ratio of the currently open document:

```
#target photoshop
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var ratio = reduce(doc.width.value, doc.height.value);
alert(ratio[0]+':'+ratio[1])

// by Phrogz see:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652468/
function reduce(numerator,denominator){
  var gcd = function gcd(a,b){
    return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
  };
  gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
  return [numerator/gcd, denominator/gcd];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1) If you are refering to internal ratio between width and height.

A ratio is not a size... it is a ratio, a relation between two mesures.

You want a photo 3:2 ratio. Is it 3x2px or 3000x2000px?

To change size of an image a crop could be needed, so it is a diferent decision you need to make.

So basicly: no.

---

Edited: The way arround is to do the math yourself.

Look at the image dimensions, for example 3000x2000px
and divide one number with the other.

In this case the aspect ratio will be 1.5. This is a way to define the aspect ratio. Here is a table of the ratios found in this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution#/media/File:Vector_Video_Standards8.svg

- 5:4=1.25
- 4:3=1.33
- 3:2=1.5
- 8:5=1.6
- 16:9=1.77
- 5:3=1.66
- 17:9=1.88
- 21:9=2.33

### 2) If you are refering to a scale

Meaning "this photo should be half of the original" 1:2

The idea its the same as percentage. Do some math:
100%/2= 50%

1:10 = 100%/10=10%.

Comment: Depends on situation if the thing your drawing is in scale for instance then the ratio make sense. Or if you know the other dimension.

Comment: I think he is asking for a derived ratio based upon the current document. (a "get", not a "set")